# iOS9 Cordova project with HTML select tag color

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, ios9

I'm working with `Cordova` project. I'm testing it in new `iOS9`, but I have a problem with the color of a select tag. In the browser and `Android`, all works fine.

HTML Code:

```
<select id="duration" class="select-sharegames action-button">


<option value="0">Fin de semana
                        <span class="ion-arrow-down-b"></span>
                    </option>
                    <option value="1">Una semana</option>
                    <option value="2">Dos semanas</option>
                    <option value="3">Un mes</option>
                    <option value="4">Otra...</option>
</select>
```

CSS Code:

```
.action-button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 51px;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #4fd2c2;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Image:

[image]

Why has the select a degraded color?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to hide the default appearance? I think that's the problem.Try this:

```
 select {
   -webkit-appearance : none;
 }
```

It hides the default styles like borders, box-shadows, border-radius, etc.
It can be applied to all form elements (input, button, textarea, etc).